# count the number of character's occuence in a text file

Tags: scilab

I want to open a text file in scilab then count the frequence of each character of ASCII code. 
So this is the script I use :

```
m=mgetl("Texte.txt")
m=strsubst(m," ","");
m=ascii(m);
format(5)
for i=1:26
f(i)=frequence(i+64,m);
if f(i)<>0 then
afficher("La fréquence de ..
"+string(ascii(i+64))+" est "+string(f(i)))
end
end
```

But i get this error : frequence is not defined. it is supposed to be used in scilab as a function. I am using scilab version 5.5.0

Thank you

Comment: Looking through the scilab documentation, I can't find a reference to `frequence` being a function. Is this a function you created? If not can you provide a link to the documentation for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [dsearch](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/en_US/dsearch.html).

```
m=mgetl("Texte.txt")
m=strsubst(m," ","");
m=ascii(strsplit(strcat(string(m))));
bins = (1:26)+64

[i_bin, counts, outside] = dsearch(m, bins,"d")

for i=1:26
    printf("%s : %d\n", ascii(bins(i)), counts(i)) 
end
```